# Error while updating SAP backend data using OData and SAP Gateway services

Tags: odata, sap-gateway

I am trying to update SAP backend using OData and SAP Gateway services. while executing it throws an error and doesn't update data in backend. I am trying to update 'accounts' data in SAP CRM backend.

The error message contains this response:

> The file {ServiceName}({BP_Number_of_that_Account}) has been successfully uploaded

This application has been deployed on to SAP Netweaver portal. I put the breakpoints in backend and found that it doesn't even reach the backend.

The code looks as follows:

```
OData.request( 
        { 
            headers: {'x-requested-with' : 'XMLHttpRequest','Content-Type': 'application/atom+xml', 'DataServiceVersion': '2.0'},
            requestUri: "/sap/Gateway/PGY/SERVICEACCOUNTS/SERVICEACCOUNTSCollection("+recordToUpdate.data.BP_NUMBER+")?sap-client=100&$format=xml", 

            method: "PUT", 
            data: {
                ACCOUNT_NAME: recordToUpdate.data.ACCOUNT_NAME,
                BP_NUMBER: recordToUpdate.data.BP_NUMBER,
                CITY: recordToUpdate.data.CITY,
                COUNTRY: recordToUpdate.data.COUNTRY,
                E_MAIL: recordToUpdate.data.E_MAIL,
                HOUSE_NO: recordToUpdate.data.HOUSE_NO,
                POSTL_COD1: recordToUpdate.data.POSTL_COD1,
                REGION: recordToUpdate.data.REGION,
                STREET: recordToUpdate.data.STREET,
                TELEPHONE: recordToUpdate.data.TELEPHONE

            },      
            user: "****", 
            password: "****"},
            function (data, response) {
                //success handler
                console.log(response);
                console.log('Successfully updated object');
            },

            function (err)
            {
                //error handler 
                console.log('error while updating');
                console.log(err);

            }
);
```

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Login to the Gateway system and check the logs in transaction /IWFND/ERROR_LOG
2. Always start transaction SRDEBUG and make sure that the breakpoints are set for the same user you are using for the request.